# How to search multiple millions of strings really fast?

Tags: php, python, mysql, database, string

So here is the situation
We have 250,000 radio stations. 
Each radio station comes with 2 strings.

These 2 strings can either be **Song Name**, **Album Name**  or **Artist Name**
We don't know which one is what. But one of them is surely the song name, we don't know which one. 
Usually  the other one is Artist(telling it for worst case scenarios, we don't want to create a situation of worst case scenario by assuming it as Album)

Now we have a database which consists of 4.5 million Artists, 7 million Albums and 150 million songs.(and a bunch of few other data which don't matter) These 3 different rows are in different tables. These are the tables where we will do our searching and matching. We can sort them Alphabetically or however it suits us to speed up the process.

These tables are interrelated.
In these tables a Song name always has an artist and album(in their respective table) associated with it, an album always has artist/s and song/s associated with......you get the idea

With 2 strings that comes with each radio station, I have to recognize 3 things

**Song Name**

**Album Name**

**Artist Name**

Now I am assuming the best case scenario would be if we match the first string of the channels with The Artist Names in the tables. If we get a match we can easily find if the other string gets a match under the Song name(and Album name) associated with the Artist matched. (Let's assume for the sake of simplicity that an Album Name cannot be same as Artist Name or song name or vice versa)
If we don't get a match for Artist with the first string, we try out the second string. and then we repeat the same with Album if we don't get a match.

What should be the algorithm for getting the fastest results ? 
I have a server of 56(using some ram already) Gb but I want to reserve 20 Gb for other purposes. (But if you can provide a very great solution by using the reserve, don't hesitate to suggest.)

We also have SSD storage. Do you think this all can be done for all the radio stations within a minute ? Preferably 30 secs?
Please let me know how to proceed.

Here is the image for better understanding

[image]

Comment: A solution based on deploying the DB in other DB solutions like 'Document DB' or 'Column Store DB' sounds like something worth further explanations? Because if it does I would love to explain.

Comment: I agree with @galdreiman I think using a different db engine optimized for text search and large tables such as Elastic Search will work much faster for your needs (since you don't have any relations between tables any way).

Comment: Are your tables well indexed for the searches that your'e doing?

Comment: You can't assume that names will be unique in the real world, though. Many artists have self-titled albums, and many song titles have been used by multiple artists.

Answer (score 2):

Well all of these are strings. It is an interesting Search problem, creating a separate specific search index (a Trie like structure) would be good. Now coming to your problem the best data structure to index your data would be a Finite State Transducer. It is much more compact than a Trie as in real world the strings and text share a lot of suffixes and an FST allows you to share suffixes as well as prefixes, think Graphs. However Trie doesn't allow you to share suffixes. Also as you would have values to your keys so you will require something like a Transducer (think sorted maps) which emits a value given a key and not a Finite State Acceptor which is more like a sorted set and not a map like structure.

Lucene has a great implementation and I suppose a lot of things like Suggestions, Edit Distances are all based on it. They have also decoupled it from their main Inverted Index.

More information on Lucene Finite State Transducers:

http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2010/12/using-finite-state-transducers-in.html

Index 1,600,000,000 Keys with Automata and Rust: http://blog.burntsushi.net/transducers/